# Очистка TextEdit Qt

Tags: qt, c++

Функция `clear()` очищает `TextEdit` только в том случае, если ее разместить после цикла, если ее запустить перед циклом, то `clear()` не работает.

Мне необходимо очистить `TextEdit` до его заполнения в цикле `while`, каким образом это сделать?

```
void Arr::Base_Out(QTextEdit *first, QTextEdit *second, QTextEdit *third, QTextEdit *fourth, QTextEdit *fives)
{
    int i = 0;

    first->setText("\0");
    second->clear();
    third->clear();
    fourth->clear();
    fives->clear();

    while (i < counter)
    {
      first->append(my_base[i].name);
      third->append(my_base[i].start);
      fourth->append(my_base[i].stop);
      i++;
    }

    third->clear();
}
```

Первое нажатие:

[image: img]

Второе нажатие. Данные перед новой загрузкой не зачистились.

[image: img2]

Comment: она срабатывает, просто Вы заполняете TextEdit снова.
Что ожидаете увидеть после запуска этого кода и что видите?

Comment: Мне нужно, что бы по нажатию кнопки, на экран вывелись данные. После повторного нажатия, TextEdit очистился и данные загрузились заново. В данный момент, после повторного нажатия кнопки данные выводятся и дописываются к старым.

Comment: данные хранятся в `my_base` ? может там и нужно очищать?

Comment: Очистить my_base я то могу, но это не выход. Мне нужно очистить TextEdit, а не удалять данные.

Comment: собрал тестовый примерчик, по аналогии с кодом выше. Никаких проблем с очисткой нет. Переменная `counter` точно остается равной 4?

Comment: Да, проблема была действительно в счетчике. Спасибо.